# Rewrite .php to directory with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to make a rewrite rule when someone enters the site and lets say he enters to index.php, then the url for him will be mysite.com/index/ and not mysite.com/index.php.
Another examle if he goes to about.php then it will be mysite.com/about/.

I hope I made it clear enough, can't make my code work(first time using htaccess).

Comment: Show up your code first.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qs4Ygk1F sry for using pastebin, code got messy in the comment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: None of my links work now :\ It just throws a 404 Error for me.
"Object not found!", but it does edit the url to /page_name/.

Comment: Which link throws 404? Make sure this is placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: I accidentally deleted one of the chars.. 
Now there's another problem, if I click the home button(href="index.php), its throwing me to URL:"localhost//". But everything else works perfectly! Thanks! Edit: fixed it, changed index.php to home.php.

Comment: please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.